# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression. in c#

Tags: c#

I am getting error on insert and update while i am providing number data in `TXT_Firm_Pincode.Text` and `TXT_Firm_Bank_Ac_No.Text` and when i am leaving this both fields empaty its working perfect can anybody help me out.

```
MC.Cmd_SQL = new OleDbCommand($@"Update TBL_Firm set 
    Firm_Owner = '{TXT_Firm_Owner.Text}', 
    Firm_Name = '{TXT_Firm_Name.Text}', 
    Firm_Address = '{TXT_Firm_Address.Text}', 
    Firm_City = '{TXT_Firm_City.Text}', 
    Firm_Pincode = @Firm_Pincode, 
    Firm_State= '{CB_Firm_State.Text}', 
    Firm_Con_Person = '{TXT_Firm_Con_Person.Text}', 
    Firm_Con_No = {TXT_Firm_Con_No.Text}, 
    Firm_GSTN = '{TXT_Firm_GSTN.Text}', 
    Firm_Bank_Name = '{TXT_Firm_Bank_Name.Text}', 
    Firm_Bank_Ac_No = @Firm_Bank_Ac_No,
    Firm_Bank_Branch = '{TXT_Firm_Bank_Branch.Text}',
    Firm_Bank_IFSC= '{TXT_Firm_Bank_IFSC.Text}',
    Firm_MailID = '{TXT_Firm_MailID.Text}' 
    where Firm_ID = {TXT_Firm_ID.Text}", MC.DB_Connection);

MC.Cmd_SQL.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

MC.Cmd_SQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firm_Pincode" , TXT_Firm_Pincode.Text == "" ? DBNull.Value : (object)"Null");

MC.Cmd_SQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firm_Bank_Ac_No", TXT_Firm_Bank_Ac_No.Text == "" ? DBNull.Value : (object)"Null"); 

MC.Cmd_SQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Why are you using `(object)"Null"`? It seems it should be `TXT_Firm_Pincode.Text` and `TXT_Firm_Bank_Ac_No.Text`, respectively

Comment: i m new to C# got this solution by googling i don't know exactly but i think to enter null value if text box is empty...

Comment: Never construct an SQL Statement from user input this way. You are prone to SQL Injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Ternary operator `condition ? operand1 : operand2` returns `operand1` when `condition` is true and false - otherwise.

It is all right with your `operand1` statement, but you need to change `operand2` to put text box value in it:

```
MC.Cmd_SQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firm_Pincode" , 
  TXT_Firm_Pincode.Text == "" ? DBNull.Value : TXT_Firm_Pincode.Text);

MC.Cmd_SQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firm_Bank_Ac_No", 
  TXT_Firm_Bank_Ac_No.Text == "" ? DBNull.Value : TXT_Firm_Bank_Ac_No.Text);
```

Comment: Thanks Miamy now its working very fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Dharmesh - please mark the answer as correct..thank you